# NextJS: Build once and get API Endpoints URL at runtime

Tags: next.js, dockerfile

I am building a new NextJS app. Currently, I am in the stage of deploying the app to multiple environments like dev, qa, staging and prod. All the environments have just one change that it uses different endpoints for API.

Now, I want to create a single dockerfile but use API_ENDPOINTS_URL based on the environment variable passed during the start command.

All the examples that I am seeing online including NextJS documentation, people are using different build commands for different environments.

```
"build:staging": "cross-env NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_URL=staging.com next build",
"start:staging": "cross-env NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_URL=staging.com next start",
"build:prod": "cross-env NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_URL=production.com next build",
"start:prod": "cross-env NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_URL=production.com next start",
```

Even the example mentioned in the NextJS github example uses 3 different dockerfiles for 3 different environments which is surprising.

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-docker-multi-env

Is it possible that I build the app once (one docker image) and send the API_URL as part of environment variable during the start command?

Comment: try this doc :- https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg

Comment: It's possible but you'll have to use [Runtime Configuration](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/runtime-configuration). The drawback is that all your pages need to be server-side rendered for the runtime config to work properly.

Comment: Where do you use this `API_ENDPOINTS_URL`, on the client side of Next.js or on the server side?

Comment: there is this comprehensive guide to environment variables in nextJs here. https://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2021/04/buildtime-vs-runtime-environment-variables-nextjs-docker/